# Creating 2 forms using form_tag inside a table (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html-table, form-for

I'd like to make a table which one column is the is the login and the other is the sign up
using pure html it is something like

```
<table id="logIn-signIn">
            <tr>
                <td class="hd">LOGIN :</td>
                <td class="hd">SIGN-UP :</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Email :
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="Email" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    First name :
                    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="First name"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Password :
                    <input type="text" name="password" value="Password"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Family name :
                    <input type="text" name="familytName" value="Family name"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    Email :
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="Email" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    Password :
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="Choose a password" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

The problem is that each column will use different fields (one for logging in and one for sign up) so each needs different form_for - one for new users and one for new session

Since the html table structure goes by rows and not columns, I can't separate the form_for blocks..

How would I use 2 different form_for blocks inside 1 table?

thanks

Comment: By using `divs` instead of `tables`.

Comment: Use CSS for layout and get rid of tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*NOTE: as the commenters have pointed out, using `divs` and `css` makes this easier, but I assume you really need to use `tables` for some reason.*

Use a nested table layout.

The outer table is for the structure - it will have one row and two columns. Inside the left cell, build a table for just the login form, and in the right cell, build a table for the sign up form. The `form_for` tags will be outside of the nested tables, but inside the cell of the layout table.

Comment: +1 even though I don't believe he really *needs* to use tables.

Comment: could someone give an explicit example of this? I have been trying to figure this out for hours :)